# Randomly show paired elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to pair elements with the same class without wrapping

```
<div class="pair1">1</div>
<div class="pair1">2</div>

<div class="pair2">3</div>
<div class="pair2">4</div>

<div class="pair3">5</div>
<div class="pair3">6</div>
```

then randomly show paired element on page refresh/load
so the output would be 1 2 or 3 4 or 5 6

[FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/artrtrkli/tQ5ZP/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use that :

```
var pairs = $('.pair1, .pair2, .pair3');

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * pairs.length / 2)+1;
var output = pairs.filter('.pair'+random)

output.show();
```

Since you have pairs, you'll need to divid the length by 2.

Then, when you have your random number, you get the pair number.

http://jsfiddle.net/tQ5ZP/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var pairs = ['.pair1', '.pair2', '.pair3'];
var div = $("div[class^='pair']");

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * pairs.length);
var output = div.filter(pairs[random]);

output.show();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ5ZP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ5ZP/5/)

```
var pairs = ['.pair1','.pair2','.pair3']; // Create an array of strings

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * pairs.length);
var output = pairs[random]; // choose a string at a random index in your array

$(output).show(); // use random string as selector
```

Or, if you have an arbitrary number of pairs you could construct your array on the fly with something like this:

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ5ZP/6/)

```
var pairs = [];

$('div').each(function() {
    var theClass = $(this).attr('class');
    pairs.push('.' + theClass);
});

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * pairs.length);
var output = pairs[random];

$(output).show();
```